# How can I remove specific regions of a 2D plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a following MATLAB plot, which consists of a rectangular domain with circular holes on it:

[image: Plot]

I am modeling a flow through that rectangular porous medium. I have plotted streamlines characterizing that flow. However, the streamlines pass through the entire mesh, which means they also pass through the circular holes on the plot. I would like to remove the streamlines from those holes.

Any suggestions on how to do that?

Here is the code I am using to create that plot:

```
x = linspace(min(X_plot(:,1)), max(X_plot(:,1)), 100); 
y = linspace(min(X_plot(:,2)), max(X_plot(:,2)), 100);
[xg, yg] = meshgrid(x, y);
Fx = TriScatteredInterp(X_plot(:,1), X_plot(:,2), qx);
Fy = TriScatteredInterp(X_plot(:,1), X_plot(:,2), qy);
qxg = Fx(xg,yg);
qyg = Fy(xg,yg); 
figure(1); hold on; 
hl = streamslice(xg, yg, qxg, qyg);
set(hl, 'color', 'b','Linewidth',0.5);
```

To plot the circles (and the ellipse) on the graph I used:

```
    hold on
    P2 = [2,-1.5];
    r2=.6;
    tt = linspace(0,pi*2);
    xx = P2(1) + r2*cos(tt);
    yy = P2(2) + r2*sin(tt);
    plot(xx,yy,'--','Color',[.7 .7 0]) 

    hold on
    P3 = [3,1.5];
    r3=1.3;
    tt = linspace(0,pi*2);
    xx = P3(1) + r3*cos(tt);
    yy = P3(2) + r3*sin(tt);
    plot(xx,yy,'--','Color',[1 .7 0]) 

    hold on
    P5 = [5,-1.5];
    r5=.8;
    tt = linspace(0,pi*2);
    xx = P5(1) + r5*cos(tt);
    yy = P5(2) + r5*sin(tt);
    plot(xx,yy,'--','Color',[1 .7 0]) 

    hold on
    P6 = [6,1.5];
    r6=.6;
    tt = linspace(0,pi*2);
    xx = P6(1) + r6*cos(tt);
    yy = P6(2) + r6*sin(tt);
    plot(xx,yy,'--','Color',[1 .7 0])


    hold on
    P4 = [9,0];
    r41=.5;
    r42=2.4;
    tt = linspace(0,pi*2);
    xx = P4(1) + r41*cos(tt);
    yy = P4(2) + r42*sin(tt);
    plot(xx,yy,'--','Color',[.9 .7 0])
```

Comment: You'll need to post the code you're using to generate the plot, and a picture of the output you're seeing. Then describe how you would like the output to be different.

Comment: Hi, The code I add here but to add a picture of the output, obviously I need some reputation that I do not have. I do not know how I can make myself clearer than this :)

Comment: x = linspace(min(X_plot(:,1)), max(X_plot(:,1)), 100);
y = linspace(min(X_plot(:,2)), max(X_plot(:,2)), 100);
[xg, yg] = meshgrid(x, y);

Fx = TriScatteredInterp(X_plot(:,1), X_plot(:,2), qx);
Fy = TriScatteredInterp(X_plot(:,1), X_plot(:,2), qy);
qxg = Fx(xg,yg);
qyg = Fy(xg,yg);

Comment: I added the code in the question @Fletch, it looks better on there

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question as we don't know what your data looks like. Can you post a couple of lines that generate sample data, so we know what you mean by "holes"?

Comment: @SanjayManohar I add a link to the question for you to see the resulting plot

Comment: @Fletch I add a link to the question for you too see the resulting plot

Comment: Ah, I see now. I thought this would be an interesting problem. Let me work on it a bit.

Comment: @Fletch, I have found some useful link I am reading it to see if it does me good. Here it is:   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9168-detect-circles-with-various-radii-in-grayscale-image-via-hough-transform

Comment: I doubt that will solve the problem, but I'm glad you're working on it to. I've solved all but one problem. I need to identify those points which comprise the outer edge of the circles. You much be generating that pattern somehow, so how are you doing it? IF you could, please post the code you're using to generate the circles in your original question. If you could also explain the contents of X_plot, that would help as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Fletch, I actually got the look that I want in my plot but in an unsophisticated way so I am still working on it. I created a filled plot (circles are filled with white) over the other one :) I add the code to plot the circles on the original question. About the X_plot it is a 2 column matrix first column being the x coordinates of the nodes of the mesh and second being the y.